# Installing Apache2 / PHP on AL2

Tags: apache-2.2, php, amazon-ec2

I've installed Apache2 and PHP as follows:

```
sudo yum install -y httpd.x86_64
sudo amazon-linux-extras install php7.2
```

I'm not able to find a libphp7.so module to load within Apache2. I loaded the httpd_modules from php, but still can't find the .so. Any suggestions?

```
$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install php7.2
Installing php-pdo, php-fpm, php-mysqlnd, php-cli, php-json
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                 | 2.4 kB  00:00:00
amzn2extra-docker                                                                                          | 1.3 kB  00:00:00
amzn2extra-httpd_5f_modules                                                                                | 1.3 kB  00:00:00
amzn2extra-php7.2                                                                                          | 1.3 kB  00:00:00
Package php-cli-7.2.8-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package php-fpm-7.2.8-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package php-json-7.2.8-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package php-mysqlnd-7.2.8-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package php-pdo-7.2.8-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
  0  ansible2                 available  [ =2.4.2  =2.4.6 ]
  1  emacs                    available  [ =25.3 ]
  2  httpd_modules=latest     enabled    [ =1.0 ]
  3  memcached1.5             available  [ =1.5.1 ]
  4  nginx1.12                available  [ =1.12.2 ]
  5  postgresql9.6            available  [ =9.6.6  =9.6.8 ]
  6  postgresql10             available  [ =10 ]
  7  python3                  available  [ =3.6.2 ]
  8  redis4.0                 available  [ =4.0.5  =4.0.10 ]
  9  R3.4                     available  [ =3.4.3 ]
 10  rust1                    available  \
        [ =1.22.1  =1.26.0  =1.26.1  =1.27.2 ]
 11  vim                      available  [ =8.0 ]
 12  golang1.9                available  [ =1.9.2 ]
 13  ruby2.4                  available  [ =2.4.2  =2.4.4 ]
 14  nano                     available  [ =2.9.1 ]
 15  php7.2=latest            enabled    \
        [ =7.2.0  =7.2.4  =7.2.5  =7.2.8 ]
 16  lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2  available  \
        [ =10.2.10_7.2.0  =10.2.10_7.2.4  =10.2.10_7.2.5
          =10.2.10_7.2.8 ]
 17  libreoffice              available  [ =5.0.6.2_15 ]
 18  gimp                     available  [ =2.8.22 ]
 19  docker=latest            enabled    \
        [ =17.12.1  =18.03.1  =18.06.1 ]
 20  mate-desktop1.x          available  [ =1.19.0  =1.20.0 ]
 21  GraphicsMagick1.3        available  [ =1.3.29 ]
 22  tomcat8.5                available  [ =8.5.31  =8.5.32 ]
 23  epel                     available  [ =7.11 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to `sudo yum install php` and after was able to find the module.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-10-22-236 ~]$ sudo find / -type f -name libphp7.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```